# Get number of enum values from instance

Tags: c#, enums, propertyinfo

I'm trying to loop through all of the enums in an object and for each enum, I need to get the number of values for its particular type. So far I have the following code:

```
var enumProps = testObj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsEnum);

foreach (var prop in enumProps)
{
       var propType = prop.GetType(); 

       var valueCount = Enum.GetValues(typeof(propType)).Length; // <-- error

}
```

The problem is that when I pass propType to typeof, I get the following error:

> propType is a variable but used as a type.

Anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: this should work: `var valueCount = Enum.GetValues(propType).Length;`

Comment: I tried that approach, however, it throws the following compile time error: "Additional information: Type provided must be an Enum."

Comment: Ahhh, I needed this to get the type: `var propType = prop.PropertyType;`

Comment: Thanks for the help. If you want to add your suggestion plus the PropertyType trick as a solution, I'd be happy to mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetType` produces the type of `prop`, which is fixed (i.e. `PropertyInfo` reflection class). You need to use `PropertyType` member, like this:

```
foreach (var prop in enumProps) {
       var propType = prop.PropertyType; 
       var valueCount = Enum.GetValues(propType).Length;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/AIxYVO)

Note that `typeof` operator is not necessary, because `propType` is already a `System.Type` that you need.

Comment: Gah, I forgot what kind of object I was dealing with.Thanks a lot for the help!